# Unit Testing UI Router Nested States

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to unit test `ui.router` nested states and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'client_view.notes' from state ''
```

I know it's something to do with how I'm setting up the states & scopes before the test.  Can someone fill me in?

**Routing:**

```
.state('client_view', {
  url: '/client/{id}',
  templateUrl: 'static/templates/client.tpl.html',
  controller: 'ClientController'
})
.state('client_view.notes', {
  url: '/notes',
  templateUrl: 'static/templates/client_notes.tpl.html',
  controller: 'ClientNotesController',
  parent: 'client_view'
})
```

**Test:**

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
client_controller = $controller('ClientController', {
  $scope: $scope,
  $state: $state
});
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
  $state.go('client_view.notes');
});
expect($scope.active('notes')).toEqual(true);
```

`$scope.active` is a method I wrote that is present in the `ClientController`.  The test will pass if set up properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have been waiting to cross this bridge of route testing myself. So I dont know exactly how to handle this situation but I can try to speculate.

As the spec doesnt have access to the whole picture of from state, maybe you can use

```
$state.current
```

to set the current state before you apply the $state.go - but this is just speculation - as the error is saying i dont know where I came from.

```
Error: Could not resolve 'client_view.notes' from state ''
```

state config [api](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#stateconfig)